# Let's fix this typo

Tags: bug, status-completed, typographical-error

On [help/reopen-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), there is a typo at the bottom of the page where the 10K Tools are discussed (*emphasis mine*):

> Commonly referred to as the "10k tools", this page **let's** you see even more information - certain anonymous flags, reopen votes, delete votes etc.

"Let's" should only ever be used as a contraction of "let us," not "to allow."

There is an [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3392/lets-vs-lets-which-is-correct) question regarding this if anyone's curious.

Another minor thing: [here is another question about whether or not the list of items in the same blockquote should have a comma before "etc."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/when-ending-a-list-with-etc-should-there-be-a-comma-before-etc)

Comment: [Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/289845). Oh. It's been fixed :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Haha, good thing neither of them have anything to do with pluralization, or it looks like I'd have a reason to be concerned!

Comment: @Zizouz212: While that one will stay a nice memory, that was in 2009.

Comment: Your title. The subtle. I like.

Comment: Plus Jeff doesn't work here any more.

Comment: @johnnyRose Any reason for that edit?

Comment: @Stijn I didn't realize editing bumped. I only edited the links because I'm OCD and prefer the shorter ones. :) Deleting temporarily until it's not on the front page...